# Problem using Promise to pass an array variable to the next function

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using Promise to ensure one ajax completes before the next starts. I am having trouble passing an array variable to the second function. When I just have the variable "numExeDetails" it works. The issue occurs when I include the second variable "exercises", which is an array. I am receiving the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') Error in exerciseOverview.js - call 'loadExerciseDetails' function"

The code is:

```
//Display the exercise table
exerciseFirstColumnDetails()
    .then((numExeDetails, exercises) => {
        loadExerciseDetails(numExeDetails, exercises)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + " Error in exerciseOverview.js - call 'loadExerciseDetails' function");//This is displayedWhen I just have the variable 
    })

function exerciseFirstColumnDetails() {

    var numExeDetails = 0;
    var exercises = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            //ajax stuff
        })
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            reject();
        })
        .done(function(responseJson1a) {
            //Do stuff to populate numExeDetails and exercises[]
            alert(numExeDetails);//Displays correct value
            alert(exercises[0]);//Displays correct value
            alert(exercises[1]);//Displays correct value
            resolve(numExeDetails, exercises);
        });
    });
});

function loadExerciseDetails(numExeDetails, exercises) {
    //Do more stuff
});
```

Comment: "*I am using Promise to ensure one ajax completes*" - no, that's no how it works. Where is your ajax code? What `resolve` function are you calling?

Comment: You can resolve a promise only with a single value, not with two at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you can pass only one argument to `resolve`.

Instead of doing `resolve(numExeDetails, exercises)` do  `resolve({ numExeDetails, exercises })`, and then you can read it like `.then(({ numExeDetails, exercises }) => {`.

There are other issues in your example, like `exerciseFirstColumnDetails` not returning an actual promise. Will pretend the example is just incomplete.

Comment: @Federfun Thank you, yes the example is incomplete and I will update it for future reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a promise in order to use `.then()`.

The wasiest way to do this is by using `return Promise.resolve()`.

```js
function exerciseFirstColumnDetails() {
  const numExeDetails = 0;
  const exercises = [];
  
  return Promise.resolve({numExeDetails, exercises});
};

function manipulateData({numExeDetails, exercises}){
  return Promise.resolve({
    numExeDetails,
    exercises: [...exercises, 123, 456, 789],
  });
}

exerciseFirstColumnDetails()
  .then(manipulateData)
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to upvote you and hit down by accident. Please amend you answer so I can correct.

Comment: @Glyn I've updated my answer.